# How do I create an unmanaged DLL using C#

Tags: c#, dll, dllexport

I have a number of C# classes that I want to expose as an unmanaged DLL.  Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to do so.  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

C# is by its very nature managed. There is no such thing as a "unmanaged" C# dll.

Also, you tagged dllexport, which is a C/C++ concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your declare the managed code as COM-Objects. This can be used from VC++....

Take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7859/Building-COM-Objects-in-C) to start...